Force to open on PWA from chrome
Currently I clicked the link on chrome browser and it opened on PWA with loading page. And then chrome browser responses api with new URL and I want to open this new URL on PWA again. But new URL can't open again on PWA. I used NextJS and next-pwa package.
I want to open again the new URL the response from chrome broswer on PWA.
I can see the loading page on PWA. But after got target_url from login API, it's still stuck on loading page.
const openWindow = window.open(
              `/loading?accessToken=${access_token}`,
              'launch',
              'width=1025px,height=600px'
            );
            addWindow(openWindow);
            loginApi(openWindow, payload);

export const addWindow= function (openWindow) {
  window.allWindowList || (window.allWindowList = []);
  window.allWindowList.push(openWindow);
};

// open new windoe after loginApi 
if (statusTranspointApi.status === 200) {
        openWindow.location.href = data.target_url;
}

